# Should non-variable column names be prepared in a prepared query?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement, sql-injection

An example given for using prepared statements with the mysql package on npm looks like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
var inserts = ['users', 'id', userId];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

'users' and 'id' here are hardcoded. userId is a variable to be provided by the user. Given that 'users' and 'id' are not provided by the user, is there any sense in including those in the query preparation? Would it be less secure to do the following?

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
var inserts = [userId];
sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
```

Comment: You should explicitly list all column and table names, included replacing `select *` with the columns you want.

Comment: The column names are listed explicitly in both examples. The question asks why the documenter went through the trouble of passing the column names as strings through the preparation function. It seems to indicate that there may be some vulnerability associated with writing the column names in the statement directly, but it's not clear why that would be the case. As for the select *, that is besides the point of the question, it's just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL parameters are used only for values, hence cannot be used for column or table names. Behind the scene, when preparing a statement, the RDBMS needs to fully understand the query that will later on be executed. Changing a column or table name does change the meaning of a query, so this is not supported.

Bottom line, you mentionned that the column and table names do not come from user input, so that removes the risk of SQL injection anyway. If they were coming from outside the program, then a solution would be to programmatically verify them (eg against predefined list of values).

Comment: My intuition is to agree that since the column name does not come from user input, that removes the risk of SQL injection. The example provided in the package documentation included the non-variable column names in the preparation, as if to indicate that if written as in my second code block, there may be vulnerabilities. I will accept this answer, that non-variable column names which are not provided by the user are not subject to modification by means of SQL injection, unless and until anyone objects in the future.